# Python: Fast range sum()

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures

I have a large time series of numbers that is a rolling window:

```
timestamps = [10, 25, 30, 32, 38]  # Much larger than this
values = [1, 3, 2, 100, 5, 32]  # Much larger than this
```

The actual size is on the order of tens or hundreds of thousands of elements.

I want to be able to compute the sum of the values between two timestamps:

```
> time_range_sum(timestamps, values, start_time=20, end_time=35)
110
```

Obviously it's easy to do this in a brute-force manner, but what's the most efficient way to do this? Are there different data structures I should be using?

Comment: Use pandas.TimeSeries

Comment: Given that the elements in values correspond to your timestamps, (assuming timestamps are unique) I feel like a dictionary might be helpful

Comment: I'm not using numpy or pandas because it's a rolling window: I need to append data to the end of timestamps and values, and remove data from the beginning as the window rolls. My understanding is that numpy/pandas are array-backed, so I can't do this efficiently. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think there's a problem creating a rolling window in a numpy array - but when you do, recognize that you don't have sorted timestamps any more...

Comment: @Floris I don't really understand what you mean. How would I have the rolling window in a numpy array with non-sorted timestamps? Also http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html says that when I append values to the rolling window, the array is recreated. Surely this is an expensive operation?

Comment: I meant "create your own rolling buffer" - compute the index of the next item to be inserted, and overwrite the value (and timestamp) at that location. Now you just need to keep track of where you "start" and "end" since it's possible that you have to sum "from the end, falling off the end, and back to the beginning". If that makes any sense. A circular buffer that overwrites the oldest data in other words.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume your time stamps are sorted. (Sort if not) Then store all the "leading sums" A[k] in an array A, where the leading sum A[k] is the sum of the first value up to the kth value in your value array. You can compute and store all the leading sums in sorted order by incrementally adding one value at a time, in total linear time. That is the preprocessing step. Then, given a range [T1,T2] of time stamps, do binary search to find out the starting index k1 and ending index k2 of times that fall within your time range. Then the answer for the range sum is A[k2] - A[k1-1] where A[0] is defined to be 0. This allows you to do each range sum in O(log n) time after O(n) time preprocessing, where n is the size of your original arrays.

Comment: Could down-voters explain why they down-voted? This seems to be the optimal solution if many range sums need to be computed.

Comment: I did some benchmarking of my own and this seemed to be the fastest solution by far

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

timestamps = np.array([10, 25, 30, 32, 38])
values = np.array([1, 3, 2, 100, 5, 32])

start_idx,end_idx = np.searchsorted(timestamps, (start_time, end_time))

time_range_sum = values[start_idx:end_idx+1].sum()
```

Comment: It might be worth posting some timings

Comment: Apologies for reposting my comment above, but: I'm not using numpy or pandas because it's a rolling window: I need to append data to the end of timestamps and values, and remove data from the beginning as the window rolls. My understanding is that numpy/pandas are array-backed, so I can't do this efficiently. Am I wrong?

Comment: You could use a numpy array as a circular buffer (i.e., keep track of the 'start' index and overwrite old data), but it would require some careful adjustments to the 'searchsorted' calls.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following to compare the `numpy` and binary search methods:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from bisect import bisect_left

ts = range(1000000);
tsnp = np.array(ts);
val = np.array(ts);
start_time = 30000;
end_time = start_time + 40000;

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
  start_idx,end_idx = np.searchsorted(tsnp, (start_time, end_time))
  sum_np = val[start_idx:end_idx+1].sum()
t1 = time.time()
print "Using numpy: time taken = ", t1 - t0
print "result = ", sum_np

def time_range_sum(timestamps, values, start_time, end_time):
    start_index = bisect_left(timestamps, start_time)
    end_index   = bisect_left(timestamps, end_time)
    return sum(values[start_index: end_index+1])

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
  q = time_range_sum(ts, ts, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time)

t1 = time.time()
print "Using bisect: time taken =", t1 - t0
print "result = ", q
```

Result:

```
Using numpy: time taken =  0.041305065155
result =  2000050000
Using bisect: time taken = 0.498136997223
result =  2000050000
```

Conclusion - numpy is about 10x faster.

Interestingly - when I reduce the window to just 40 (instead of 40000) the results change:

```
Using numpy: time taken =  0.0219249725342
result =  1230820
Using bisect: time taken = 0.00494909286499
result =  1230820
```

So `bisect` is faster when it comes to searching, and `numpy` is faster for the summing... Which means that the best method will be a function of the window size. Clearly it's worth doing a bit of benchmarking if you want to optimize.

Comment: Since it's a rolling window, I have to store the data in a list or deque or something similar. So you have to add in the time of the np.array() calls for the numpy approach.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the `bisect_left` approach 1000 times, but the numpy approach only once. Doesn't seem like a fair comparison...

Comment: @perimosocordiae - you are completely right, sloppy coding on my part. I fixed it - and now conclusions are different (and more interesting).  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

Assuming, Time-stamp is sorted, use binary search to determine the start and end index of start_time and end_time and use those index to slice the values list and then sum the sublist.

**Implementation **

```
def time_range_sum(timestamps, values, start_time, end_time):
    from bisect import bisect_left
    start_index = bisect_left(timestamps, start_time)
    end_index   = bisect_left(timestamps, end_time)
    return sum(values[start_index: end_index+1])
```

**Demo**

```
timestamps = [10, 25, 30, 32, 38]
values = [1, 3, 2, 100, 5, 32]
time_range_sum(timestamps, values, start_time=20, end_time=35)
110
```

**Timing**

```
In [9]: from random import randint

In [10]: timestamps = range(10,10000,10)

In [11]: values = [randint(1,10) for _ in  range(len(timestamps))]

In [12]: %paste
def time_range_sum(timestamps, values, start_time, end_time):
        from bisect import bisect_left
        start_index = bisect_left(timestamps, start_time)
        end_index   = bisect_left(timestamps, end_time)
        return sum(values[start_index: end_index+1])

## -- End pasted text --

In [13]: %timeit time_range_sum(timestamps,values,start_time=20,end_time=9000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.8 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find the beginning of the list and the end using divide and conquer, and then sum using sublists. You can use numpy for the sum part, it will be faster.

Comment: This will work if the list is ordered on the timestamps.

Comment: The timestamps example is sorted, and it is meaningfull for timestamps to be sorted.

Comment: The timestamps are sorted. Would you recommend using bisect for this approach?